# Sharing menu info (button info) when replacing a scene in Cocos2D

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone

In order to figure out what level is selected, I want to share the selected button information to the replaced scene.. How can I do that?

```
CCLabelBMFont *label = [CCLabelBMFont labelWithString:@"Lavel_2" fntFile:@"font.fnt"];
        CCMenuItemLabel *titem = [CCMenuItemLabel itemWithLabel:label target:self selector:@selector(sceneLoader:)];
        CCMenu *menu = [CCMenu menuWithItems: titem, nil];
        menu.position = ccp(screenSize.width/2, screenSize.height/2);
        [self addChild:menu];


- (void)sceneLoader:(id)sender {
    [[CCDirector sharedDirector] replaceScene: [GameLayer scene]];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

tag your item and then set the tag to your GameLayer

something like this...

```
titem.tag = 777;

...

- (void)sceneLoader:(CCNode)sender {
    GameLayer *gameLayer = [GameLayer scene];
    gameLayer.gameLevel = sender.tag;

    [[CCDirector sharedDirector] replaceScene: gameLayer];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create separate initializers for your scene. Or at least one with an enum:

```
[[GameLayer alloc] initWithButton:kSceneLoaderButton];
```

Answer (score -1):

For that kind of operation I use singletons

file.h

```
@interface YourClassName : NSObject
+ (id)sharedInstance;
@property (nonatomic,retain) NSString * selectedLevel;
```

file.m

```
@implementation YourClassName
@synthesize selectedLevel;
+ (id)sharedInstance {
    static YourClassName *sharedInstance = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        sharedInstance = [[self alloc] init];
    });
    return sharedInstance;
}

- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        selectedLevel = [NSString string];
    }
    return self;
}
```

and if You want use it just call `[[YourClassName sharedInstance] selectedLevel` or for set `[[YourClassName] setSelectedLevel]`

Hope that will help You.